# Replace em textos não definidos

Tags: c#

Tenho uma dúvida referente ao replace, estou populando valores em word porém alguns valores eu não irei ter disponivel mas se não preencher no word será mostrado @@NomeVariavel, então queria saber se tem algum replace geral para colocar nos valores que eu não tenho nos @@variavelxpto o valor "0,00"

```
if (row["id_evento"].ToString() == "8")
{
    sbConteudo.Replace("@@fdfgertyer", row["VALOR"].ToString());
}
else if (row["id_evento"].ToString() == "10")
{
    sbConteudo.Replace("@@zz", row["VALOR"].ToString());
}
else if (row["id_evento"].ToString() == "22")
{
    sbConteudo.Replace("@@xsa", row["VALOR"].ToString());
}
else if (row["id_evento"].ToString() == "24")
{
    sbConteudo.Replace("@@teste", row["VALOR"].ToString());
}
else if (row["id_evento"].ToString() == "98")
{
    sbConteudo.Replace("@@VALOR_IDES_2", row["VALOR"].ToString());
}
else if (row["id_evento"].ToString() == "99")
{
    sbConteudo.Replace("@@VALOR_IDES_1", row["VALOR"].ToString());
}
```

No exemplo que eu usei digamos que eu tenho o evento 24,10 e 99 então será mantido a variavel @@valor_ides_2 e @@teste, mas eu preciso colocar 0 lá. Em alguns casos a variavel que não sera preenchida será outras então não possuo um padrão.

Comment: Porque não percorre as variáveis ao invés de procurar os ids ?

Comment: @RovannLinhalis obrigado pelo comentário, não entendi bem sua proposta, como ficaria?

Comment: Coloquei a resposta de como eu faria, veja se te ajuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sugeri que fizesse a substituição pelas variáveis.

Imagino que tenha uma lista com todas as variáveis e qual id_evento deve ser buscado quando for aquela variavel, assim você pode montar um `Dictionary`:

```
Dictionary<string,string> variaveis = new Dictionary<string,string>();
variaveis.Add("@@NOME","10");
variaveis.Add("@@TESTE","22");
variaveis.Add("@@EVENTO","24");
```

Depois, você percorre os pares de valores, e troca:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> v in variaveis)
{
    string valor  = "0";
    DataRow[] rows  = dataTable.Select("id_evento = "+ v.Value); //Procura no datatable, se há registros com o respectivo id referente a variavel atual
    if (rows.Length >0) //se não houver, não altera o valor, mantendo 0
    {
       valor = rows[0]["VALOR"].ToString();
    }
    //substituio a variavel pelo valor
    sbConteudo.Replace(v.Key, valor);
}
```

Dessa forma, todas as variáveis previamente definidas serão substituídas. E quando for necessário adicionar outras variáveis, basta adiciona-las ao dicionário, o restante do código permanece igual.

Comment: De fato o código ficou muito mais limpo e eficaz porém infelizmente não resolveu meu problema, por exemplo,  se no banco de dados ( datatable ) não possuir o evento 10, no meu word ficará @@NOME e eu gostaria que todos os @@.* que não foram preenchidos ficassem com 0,00. seria como o exemplo do  Carlos ali em cima, mas estou testando porque o word não consegue gerar com o exemplo que ele usou.

Comment: Nesse exemplo, se não houver o id_evento=10, será colocado "0" no lugar. Se @@NOME está na lista de variáveis, o foreach vai passar por ela e trocar o valor.

Comment: Perfeito Ronavann resolveu minha dúvida, seria isso mesmo. Surgiu uma dúvida aqui mas eu já vou marcar que a sua resposta é a correta. Acontece que o meu datatable tem por exemplo evento 8,10,12,14,8,14.
esse 8 e 14 que repetiu é do mês posterior então se eu fizer o mesmo select nesse datatable ele vai me retornar o valor do primeiro 8 entende ? teria alguma solução para isso ?
exemplo: 8,10,12,14 mês dezembro 8,14 mês janeiro mas se eu fizer esse select ele vai me retornar o valor de dezembro as 2 vezes porque ele é o primeiro.

Comment: Talvez se eu excluísse a linha depois da ação...

Comment: você tem a coluna mês no datatable ?

Comment: Tenho na verdade a data do movimento que seria o mês : (01/01/2017) e (01/01/2018)

Comment: mas aí tem um problema cara... vc sempre vai ter que ficar atualizando seu código. Tem que pensar em algo que funcione sempre... se o id_evento mudar você vai ter q mudar o código

Comment: o Id do movimento nunca vai mudar, tenho certeza disso mas o evento mudaria, eu só preciso pegar por exemplo 4 eventos do mes 01 e 2 eventos no mes 2 só que no mês 1 é o mesmo Id do 2 então eu teria que remover do data table pra não haver conflito, entende?

Comment: acho que nesse caso, mexe no select para só trazer os mais novos, filtrando pelo mes

Comment: daqui um pouco vou apagar os comentários

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar uma expressão regular:

```
        if (row["id_evento"].ToString() == "8")
        {
            sbConteudo.Replace("@@fdfgertyer", row["VALOR"].ToString());
        }
        else if (row["id_evento"].ToString() == "10")
        {
            sbConteudo.Replace("@@zz", row["VALOR"].ToString());
        }
        else if (row["id_evento"].ToString() == "22")
        {
            sbConteudo.Replace("@@xsa", row["VALOR"].ToString());
        }
        else if (row["id_evento"].ToString() == "24")
        {
            sbConteudo.Replace("@@teste", row["VALOR"].ToString());
        }
        else if (row["id_evento"].ToString() == "98")
        {
            sbConteudo.Replace("@@VALOR_IDES_2", row["VALOR"].ToString());
        }
        else if (row["id_evento"].ToString() == "99")
        {
            sbConteudo.Replace("@@VALOR_IDES_1", row["VALOR"].ToString());
        }

        string pattern = "@@.*";
        string replacement = "0";
        Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
        string sbConteudo = rgx.Replace(sbConteudo, replacement);
```